# Where is UV/Image editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to map a unwrapped cube texture on an actual cube. I found many tutorials that talk about unwrapping the model and working on the UV map, but there is literally no information on where to open the editor in the first place.

So simple question: how to open the editor and view my unwrapped cube?

Comment: split your current window to create a new one and in the dropdown menu that you'll find on the top left, select UV Editor. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to illustrate Moonboots' comment with a gif :).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Blender is a great tool, but it is really hard on newbies.

Comment: No question about that :).